# Is there a rest api call available to add or update subscriber information to the list

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I am not using Fuel SDK and I am working on Java Platform using Spring. I have a requirement to add or update subscriber information using api calls if there is one available.

Q. Just like I have a Url to send mail to the subscriber using rest api, is there a way I can add or update subscriber to the list. Below is the call for email and I am looking for something similar or really an alternate way without using SOAP.

https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{0}/send?access_token={1}